# Is there a way to transform XML into XSL using XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

so my problem is that I have a bunch of xml files, upwards of 100, that I would like to write xsl's for to add their default values. I was wondering if there was a way to write an xsl that will transform all of these xml's into an xsl format. The only other way I can think to do it at the moment is by hand so I figured I would ask before I started down that long path.

Here is an excerpt from one of my XMLs:

```
<value name="dt" field="dt"/>
<value name="qdd" field="qdd"/>
```

And this is my current XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/../../..">
    <xsl:copy>

        <!-- copy whatever was already there -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>

        <xsl:if test="not(qdd)">
            <qdd>0</qdd>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The desired XML output is this:

```
 <value name="dt" field="dt"/>
 <value name="qdd" field="qdd" default="0"/>
```

However, knowing that order needs to be preserved will I need to manually add each value into the xsl? I ask because some of the xmls have 20-30 children. Basically I just want to remove the default values in the xml and move them into the xsl.

Comment: XSLT is XML so XSLT can create XSLT as its result, usually done using the https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-namespace-alias. You will need to show samples of the XML and XSLT you have in mind to allow us to tell whether that is necessary and you can't simply use parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Do you want to transform test.xml into test.xsl which you then want to use for other transformations? (Indeed possible). Or do you want to have A SINGLE xsl sheet that is capable of removing the "default values" from your 100 xml files? (That depends on the structure of your 100 xml files)

Comment: @MartinHonnen Changes made. Hopefully this explains it a bit more.

Comment: @nCessity I am looking at either option at this point, I would normally just remove the defaults but ordering needs to be preserved which could present a problem. Hopefully my edits I just made better explain my problem.

Comment: Please add your desired output xml as well, thanks!

Comment: @nCessity there ya go. Thanks for reminding me lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Removing the attribute

Just copy everything but the default attribute:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value/@default" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### And the other way round

Add the desired attribute to elements which meet certain conditions while copying everything:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value[@name='qdd']" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="default">0</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hey man, I really appreciate your answer but I goofed up the order in which I wanted the default done. Added not removed, sorry for the insane amount of confusion, it has been a long morning in the office.

Comment: @AAlred: I added the other way round. Hope that helps!

Comment: It looks like it works! Does this preserve order as well? It did for my example but I am wondering if it works in any case

Comment: Yes, it does preserve the order.